# Installed Root Certificate does not appear in Certificate Trust Settings

Tags: iphone, certificate, configuration-profiles

I have an iPad Pro and an iPhone SE both running iOS 13.3.1

I successfully installed a root certificate on the iPad and was able to "Enable Full Trust for Root Certificates" from `Settings/General/About/Certificate Trust Settings`.

When I attempt to install the same profile on the iPhone, it installs correctly, but the certificate does not appear in the `Certificate Trust Settings` screen so that I can enable full trust.

I've tried removing and reinstalling the profile, as well as power-cycling the phone.

**Question:** What do I need to do to get the certificate to show up in the `Certificate Trust Settings` panel?

Screenshot of installed profile:

[image: Screenshot of installed profile]

Screenshot of `Certificate Trust Settings` panel

[image: Screenshot of <code>Certificate Trust Settings</code> panel]

Comment: Jim, did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue on an old iphone se

Comment: No, I gave up and switched to a LetsEncrypt certificate, which has been working just fine.